# Using cropmarks

Tags: adobe-indesign, bleed, margin

My InDesign document is `195 mm x 280 mm`, has a `4mm` bleed, `0mm` slug and `10mm` margin. My client specified:

> Size: `195 x 280 + 4 mm` bleed. Cropmarks should be used.

What does that mean? Should I draw lines where the bleed edges are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crop marks are automatically created during pdf export. You just gotta make sure you enable it in the export settings.

Exporting can be found in: `File > Export` or <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> *( <kbd>Cmd+E</kbd> in mac )*

---

When you are exporting a pdf, you gotta go to `Marks and bleeds` and select `Crop marks`.

You may also need to select `Use document bleed settings`.

[image]