# What is the correct bleed number for A4 and A5 documents in InDesign CS6?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, print-design, document-setup

I face a great challenge in knowing what exactly bleed should I use in my document with A4 and another in A5. Actually, this will help me to guide printers on what should they suppose to crop.

Comment: What do you mean "bleed number"? the amount of bleed? I usually stick to 3mm bleed on my documents intended for print

Comment: This question should be consulted with the printer..

Answer (score 1):

There's no "exact" amount of bleed.

There's often a minimum which can vary, but generally if you use .25", 1p6, or 3mm (as @SaturnsEye suggests) things are fine.

Print providers use **crop marks** to know where crop. They do not measure in from the outer bleed edge. The size of your bleed is largely irrelevant as long as *some* bleed exists.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Scott and Saturn's useful input, it may be best just to ask your printer how much bleed they want to use. For regular-sized products like the A4 and A5 you mention, a standard size like 3mm or .25" should be fine.

Be aware that, using most publishing software like InDesign or QuarkXPress (if anyone still uses that...), you can create `pdf` files with bleed and crop marks included.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to setup a document with a bleed:

- InDesign go to `File -> New`
- Make sure to set `Intent` to `Print`:

[image]

- Set `Page Size` to `A4` or `A5`:

[image]

- Click the expand button and the Bleed and Slug will appear:

[image]

- How to setup crop marks on file export:

[image]

In regards to "what bleed should I use" I would consult the printer because they may already have a template prepared for you.  Reference: "[What should you ask the printer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/what-should-you-ask-the-printer)".  If you are mistaking crop marks for bleed reference: "[Using cropmarks](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30254/using-cropmarks)"